# Reason for adding libxml2?

Tags: fmdb

Both FMDB and TouchXML are outside fraweworks. But we need to add -libxml2 flag while  implementing TouchXML and we don't add any flag while implementing FMDB. Can anybody explain this to me ?

Answer (score 0):

fmdb is **NOT** a framework. It's a objective-C **wrapper**. you will need to add the sqlite3 flag if you are linking against the sqlite3 lib installed in your system. If you just use the sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h, you do not need to add the sqlite3 flag.